# Why would Gmail ask for the last password I remember?

Tags: password-management

Yesterday I tried to recover the password for a Gmail account that I have created few months ago and during the process it asked me for the last password I remember. Why would it ask for that?

[image]

- I'm 100% sure that I have used only ONE password for the account so it's meaningless to ask me for the last password I used in case they were trying to verify my identity using old passwords
- I assume Gmail does not store the passwords in clear text so I highly doubt it's helpful for them if I remember my password as `Password123` instead of the right one `password1234` as they have totally different hashes.

Comment: Have you considered the fact that they might keep more than one password hash as history ?

Comment: Sure. Thats why I explained that I have used only ONE password. Many websites these-days store hashes to prevent using the a password that you have used before.

Comment: What are you asking then ? You Do realize that password recovery is not tailored to your own personal usage. Asking a user for a previously remembered password could be help the case a lot if, for instance, you happen to have changed your password recently and failed to remember your new one. This seems so obvious an answer that I doubt that is what you really are asking for

Comment: Well I've just created a new Gmail account, tried to recover the password and it asked me the last password I remember. I simply assumed that they are smart enough to figure out that 1)obviously I dont know that password 2)the account has no old passwords. So there must be a reason for them to ask for "what I remember of the password"

Comment: Tailoring the password recovery process in such a way would disclose information about the password.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like GMail knows the hashes of earlier passwords for users. While this is not true in your case, treating it as a special case would cost the developers time, and it would provide attackers a clue about your password habits. It is a good thing that GMail doesn't advertise that you never changed your password.

Answer (score 3):

Beyond the obvious "don't make it more complex that you have to", there are tow reasons why a password recovery process shouldn't attempt to tailor the challenge to the known data:

- It is a form of information disclosure (in your case, it would indicate that the password has not been changed since it was created)
- It doesn't actually change the result of the challenge in any meaningful way.